# Celery - Reuse a broker connection with apply_async()

Tags: python, django, celery

We have a Django app that uses Celery's apply_async() call to send tasks to our RabbitMQ server. The problem is that when there are thousands of requests coming into the Django app, each apply_async() call will cause it to open thousands of new connections to the RabbitMQ server.

In the [Celery documentation for apply_async](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async), there is a **connection** parameter:

> connection – Re-use existing broker connection instead of establishing a new one.

My question is, how can I use it in a Django app? I cannot find any examples of how to use this. We are running Django using Gunicorn, ideally we would like to have each worker create one connection to the broker and re-use it between requests. In this way, the number of connections opened on the broker is limited by the amount of workers running.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Oh wow, this was 3 years ago so I'll answer this as best as I can. Due to our architectural decisions with that app at the time we were not able to find a clean solution for this. We simply decided to scale out our RabbitMQ servers to handle the large number of connections. If you're using gunicorn with gevent, you might want to explore using `Greenlet.spawn_tree_locals` http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.greenlet.html#gevent.Greenlet.spawn_tree_locals to store Kombu connection objects.